# Geometry inequality proof

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

[image: Help with this proof?]

I started off with the given and by using the triangle inequality theorem but I don't know what to do next. Can someone please help? Thank you very much. I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

$\angle ADC>\angle ACD$ and, because are both on first quadrant, then $\sin(ADC)>\sin(ACD)$.  Finally, using the sin rule, then $AD<AC$

Comment: can you show this using basic geometric proof? Trying to refresh myself for tutoring a high school course

Comment: Other: use Pythagoras

Comment: If ADH and AHC are right triangles, with the same height AH and DH<HC, use Pythagoras

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the triangle inequality.

We observe that the length

$|AS| + |AD| = |SD|$ (*)

because $|AS|$ and $|AD|$ are on the same line.

However,

$|AS| + |AC| > |SC| = |SD|$ (**)

due to the triangle inequality. The strict inequality is because $|AS|$ and $|AC|$ do not lie in the same line. (Verify this, please).

We have

$|AD| = |SD| - |AS|$ by (*)

and

$|AC| > |SD| - |AS| = |AD|$ by (**).

So $|AC| > |AD|$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You have $SA+AD=SD=SC$.

Also, because the sum of the lengths of two sides of the triangle is bigger than the length of the third side you have $SA+AC>SC$.

So you have $SA+AC>SA+AD$ from which follows $AC>AD$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\overline{SD}=\overline{SC}$, $\triangle SDC$ is isosceles, and therefore, $L$, the locus of points that are equidistant from $C$ and $D$, is the line through $S$ perpendicular to $\overline{CD}$. Since $A$ is on the same side of $L$ as $D$, $A$ is closer to $D$ than to $C$. That is,
$$
\overline{AD}\lt\overline{AC}
$$